cvxpy diagonal matrix as variable
Given some constraints (useless for this question), I want to minimize -log(det(M)) for some diagonal n x n matrix M.
Usually, we do this for symmetric matrices, so that M = cvxpy.Variable((n, n), diagonal=True) does the job. In the present situation, refering to https://www.cvxpy.org/api_reference/cvxpy.atoms.affine.html#diag, I would try something like
M = cvxpy.diag(vec, 0) where vec = cvxpy.Variable(n), but this does not work (I get errors depending on what I try: even this answer did not work for me).
Any suggestion about how to define this variable diagonal matrix?

If M is a diagonal matrix then det(M) is the product of the entries. Does it help?

@StéphaneLaurent No I do not know how this could help, sorry. This is more about the syntax (how to define things properly) that the maths behind.
